# Pulling portion of file and storing in a variable within a Batch File

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a file that contains some information about the product I work on. The information I'm specifically interested in is the version of the product.

I need to read in this version and store it in a variable that I can manipulate so I can increment the version number appropriately. I'm trying to use a line like this:

```
for /f "tokens=2" %%i in ('type product.properties^|find "about.version=Version"') do set currentversion=%%i
```

I know that the file contains the string "about.version=Version" and it is immediately followed by a space and then the Version number. However when I try and echo %currentversion% there is nothing stored in it.

I'm on Windows XP, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On note: You don't need `type`, just give `find` the file name.

If you are doing above thing in a `for` loop, `if` statement or any other kind of parenthesized block in the batch file, then enable delayed expansion with

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpasion
```

earlier in the batch file first and use `!currentversion!` instead of `%currentversion%`.

Comment: Rössel: So I tried removing the type call, played with it as much as I can but I can't get it to actually make the find call and search that. It just searches the 'find "about.version=Version" product.properties' and stores "about.version into %currentversion%

Comment: Nevermind I just played with it more and got it to work using a way I swear I had tried already. Thanks.